# Find overlapping numbers in C++

Tags: c++

I have the code that does not exactly work and cannot find the edge case here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int meetings;
    cin >> meetings;

    vector<int> start(meetings);
    vector<int> end(meetings);
    for (int i = 0; i < meetings; i++) {
        cin >> start[i] >> end[i];
    }

    int overlap = meetings;
    for (int i = 0; i < meetings; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < meetings; j++) {
            if (start[i] < end[j] && start[j] < end[i]) {
                overlap--;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << overlap << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Basically, I need to have the **user input** like this:

```
3 - number of cases
10 20 - case 1 - start and end
12 25 - case 2
20 30 - case 3
```

**Output:**

Number of non overlapping meetings: 2 (case 2 is overlapping with case 1; but case 1 and case 3 are fine).

What am I missing here?

Edit: sorted the pair vectors as suggested and then it was easy. Cheers

Comment: What is an "overlapping number"? your question is not clear. Also, did you try running through your debugger? On another note, `int start[meetings], end[meetings];` is not valid c++. Whatever resource you're using to learn c++ that teaches that is crap.

Comment: Just put it in a compiler and it compiles perfectly fine, but the if loop is probably missing something.

I want to define n number of cases with the starting minute and ending minute. 

one meeting is 6:10-6:20
second meeting 6:12-6:25 - so impossible, because it has a conflict with another meeting
third meeting - 6:20-6:30 - ok, cuz no conflict with the first case

I only need to operate with the minutes, no need for specific time.

Comment: _it compiles perfectly fine_ actually, no, it doesn't, in a standard compliant compiler, it does not compile, since it's not valid standard c++ code. But that's beside the point. When you step through with your debugger, what do you see?

Comment: I think your if statement is wrong.  It should be `if (start[i] < end[j] && start[i] >= start[j] || end[i] <= end[j] && end[i] > start[j])` because that checks the start and end of the first period with the second period.

Comment: Recommendation: rather than two parallel arrays, consider making a structure to contain the big and end values and have an array of that. Usually a bit faster and a lot easier to manipulate.

Comment: Comparing ranges is a bit of a headache because there are so many combinations. Are the start and end points part of the range (or like Python, start point is, end point is not)? A can be within B, B can be within A, A can start outside B and end inside, or start inside and end outside. One thing that might simplify things a bit is a function with checks that apply to both A relative to B and B relative to A so you only need to code half the checks. But in the end you do need to do the work to enumerate all possibilities.

Comment: Alright, cool did it with sorted vector pairs and it seems to work! Cheers guys

Comment: This problem has multiple solutions. If you want to take into account the order in which you received the inputs, they should not be sorted because that way you won't know which meeting overlapped first. If you are not interested in preserving the order and you want them to be sorted, then you have to decide which condition is appropriate: whether the left value or the right value should be prioritized in cases of overlap.

Comment: You can think of it this way: you have 4 meetings in your calendar that do not overlap and were scheduled some time ago. Now, someone comes and schedules a meeting that overlaps with one of the existing meetings. Which one do you choose to attend?

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted `int start[meetings]` is not valid C++ (although many compilers have extentions that allow it), it should be replaced by either `std::vector<int> start(meetings)` (needs `#include<vector>`) but other solutions are also available.

Now to the logic of your program: it is possible that intervals can overlap with more of one other interval, but the `break` inside the `if` statement breaks the inner loop when the first one is encountered, missing the ones after.

Also, it seems you're assuming the intervals are sorted